# What is the sign of Weinberg angle?

Tags: standard-model, conventions, electroweak

One has $\cos{\theta_W}=m_W/m_Z$, and $\sin^2{\theta_W}=1-(m_W/m_Z)^2$

Is the sign of the Weinberg angle defined or an important quantity?

If yes, are there constraints?

Comment: @innisfree yes : sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle).

It is *taken* to be positive, since, then, the (small) hypercharge coupling is positive, $$g'=\sqrt{g^2+g'^2} ~\sin\theta_W .
$$

You already know that the sign of the angle does not matter when it comes to the quadratic form to be diagonalized: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} B & W^3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \tan^2 \theta_W & -\tan\theta_ W\\-\tan\theta_W & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B \\ W^3 \end{pmatrix} .
$$
If you defined it oppositely, you'd simply get the same vanishing determinant for the mass-squared matrix and essentially the same state eigenvectors mutatis mutandis--in this case the sign of the angle.

The PDG and WP take special pains to focus on sign-independent quantities.

Comment: I think I agree. On the other hand, $g^\prime$ positive isn’t a convention, is it? So suddenly it feels odd to say the sign of the angle is a convention

Comment: I'd call it a convention, in the absence of macroscopic/classical hypercharge forces, sort of like the convention of the electric charge definition in the pre-SM days, no?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Kind regards